# Using Taylor polynomials to find a natural defnition of an undefined equation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find the natural definition of $g(0) = {e^x-1\over x}$ by finding the Taylor series of $e^x$ to three degrees, since $g(0)$ is undefined

when I do this, I get $e^x=1+x+{x^2\over2!}++{x^3\over3!}$

I'm stuck from here on, when I substitute the definition for $e^x$ and let $x=0$ I'm exactly where I started. Not to mention the denominator is still zero.

Comment: Don't let $x = 0$ yet! First substitute that approximation for $e^x$, subtract 1, and divide by $x$ to simplify. Then you can plug in $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The series expansion for Exp(x)-1 is the same series that you just posted, except you have to delete the first term of that series, which is 1. After that, you are left with terms that are all power functions of x, which means you can factor out at least one x and reduce the powers of x in the rest of your terms by exactly one. Since you have x in the denominator and now a factored out x from your series, you can cancel them out.

Edit: This is all justified because the Exponential function is in the numerator, so its series expansion converges for any real or complex x.

Comment: You mean $x$ in the denominator, not $x^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh yes my apologies, I should edit that out! Good eyes you have.

Comment: No need to apologise. We all make mistakes here and there. I, for one, have made - and continue to make - my share. As for my eyes, I'm afraid they're anything but good at my age. :) Oh, and just a suggestion about style. You might want to consider learning how to write math using LaTeX. It's the standard around here. Here's a [guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Much appreciated for the guide! Been wondering how everyone is looking so cool with their font!